# « Être dans les jambes l’un l’autre », « Être dans les jambes l’un de l’autre » ou « Être chacun dans les jambes de l’autre »

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Ça ne sert à rien que tu m’aides à huiler le plancher,

…nous serons dans les jambes l’un l’autre.

…nous serons dans les jambes l’un de l’autre.

…nous serons chacun dans les jambes de l’autre.

…tu seras dans mes jambes et réciproquement.

——————————————————

Au sens de « se nuire mutuellement », « s’entre-nuire ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ma mère utilisait beaucoup cette expression.

En partant de vos exemples:

> *Ça ne sert à rien que tu m’aides à huiler le plancher, tu seras dans mes jambes.*

Je n'ai jamais entendu l'expression "dans les jambes l'un de l'autre". Ça sonne faux.

Le "et réciproquement" n'est pas nécessaire.

Ceci dit... L'expression, en général, s'utilise quand on est déjà dans les dites jambes. Comme une interjection.

> *Tu es dans mes jambes là, vas-t-en!*

Dans le future, on utiliserait plutôt quelque chose comme:

> *[...], on va se marcher dessus.*
>
> *[...], ça va être trop serré.*

Answer (score 2):

*Pas besoin que tu m’aides à huiler le plancher. Si on le fait à deux, je serai toujours dans tes pattes et toi dans les miennes.*

Comment: J'ai toujours entendu celui-ci, majoritairement dans des zones rurales.